# C# thread execution time changing

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, stopwatch

I have a C# application to learn about multithreads.
This application triggers 4 threads at the same time and each threads do the same operations. Thread function just as below

```
        Watch_Task4.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        Watch_Task4.Stop();
```

But when I measure the thread times, sometimes they are different approximately 10ms. While the code is runnig I analyzied CPU usage and its maximum %25. I also use ThreadPriority.Highest for my all threads.

So why the execution time is changing between threads and for same thread at each trials while CPU is not overloading?

I tried ProcessorAffinity but the result ise same. I need at least 1ms repeatibility.

Comment: _This application triggers 4 threads at the same time_ there is no 4 threads in your code sample

Comment: It is just an example of a thread function. I edited my question. Thank you

Comment: If your system is not real-time systems(I'm not sure though it is), you cannot manage their running order as well as priority. You with `ThreadPriority.Highest` just impetrates operating system to "would you mind behaving the thread specified with this flag higher ranked?" It is most fundamental thing taught in a university in computer science/engineering department. Even you say, 4 threads, but the number is also just kindly request. There is no guarantee for spawning four of them at once.  The OS may preempt any of the threads whenever it wants. Anlatabildim mi abi?

Comment: It is not possible. You cant run two threads absolutely paralel. procesor is running some instructions per cycle.

Comment: Also Threads and Tasks are not same. Think about that.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @snr - Reinstate Monica  My system is not real time. I run my project on Win7 64 bit PC. Okay I understood the difference between threads. But what about the same thread? As I understood there is no way to do a performance critical and time predictable project with C#.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Win7 64 bit

Comment: A must read: [Processes, Threads, and Jobs in the Windows Operating System](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7). (2009, part of the book), and to buy the latest: https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-internals-part-1-system-architecture-processes-9780735684188

Comment: If you are supposed to be very crucious about performance, you need to write your own OS, like siemens, ibm. These semantics are nothing but related to OS in lieu of a language.

Comment: @OguzOzgul even with the fact that a program whose crux point is performance can’t be established perfectly.

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica Totally agree. The reason I shared the reading is that it clearly shows how unpredictable the timings for thread switches can be. Thread.Sleep(1) does not guarantee waking up after exactly 1 ms, and that part from the book tries to explain why.

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica, if you will, do you know if it does make any difference to have a kernel mode driver on windows? According to this, still no: https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2014-issue3/windows-real-time/

Comment: The lowest execution resolution of windows is one 60th of a second. You can only measure down to 1000 / 60 milliseconds - of 16.666666 ms. You can't get down to 1 ms.

Comment: @Enigmativity: interesting, the [docs says otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps). They have an example C# code that let's you measure much shorter intervals than 16ms.

Comment: @WiktorZychla high resolution measurements are possible. The problem is with high resolution notifications (events, callbacks). If you want something to happen exactly after 1000 msec, you can't rely on the system sending you a notification at exactly the right moment. Your could try measuring non-stop in a tight loop, and hope that your thread will have its time-slice from the operating system at the critical moment.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: that's correct. It's just *you can only measure down to 16ms* is misleading and would confuse anyone reading this.